# condition for the commutativity of associative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

$R$ is an associative algebra over a field $F$ of positive characteristic $p$, if every element $x$ of $R$ satisfies $x^{p^{n(x)}}=x$ for some $n(x)>1$, can we proof that $R$ is abelian? if not, can we give a counterexample?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried looking at various subalgebras of the endomorphism ring? What can you say?

Comment: When you write "abelian" do you mean "commutative"?  Abelian is used differently in the literature.  If you mean that, then this question is a duplicate.  Also, please see [this advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) about including enough context.

Answer (score 0):

By [Jacobson's theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/93178/19965) it is **commutative**. You can even forget the hypothesis about the characteristic and that it is an algebra. The proof works for any ring.

Because it is commutative and satisfies that condition, it is also reduced, and reduced rings are **abelian** (meaning idempotents are all central.)